# My Panasonic TC-50A400U turns off and on when connected to my PC with an HDMI cable

Tags: tv

I have my Panasonic TV connected to my PC via HDMI cable, but it keeps losing signal I guess?

The screen goes blank for about 20 seconds then goes back to displaying my extended PC desktop. The TV doesn't turn off technically, but it looks like it's losing signal

Any help/ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: On the chance that the problem isn't with the TV, what's on the other end of the cable? (computer model, graphics card, operating system)  Has it always done this or has something changed?  Does it happen immediately upon cold computer start or only after things are warmed up?  What have you tried? (different cable?  different connection method?)  Does everything else work normally (no problems with a standard monitor)?  If you connect the TV to a TV signal or DVR, does it work properly?

Comment: It's a computer i built myself. I bought all the parts online and assembled it on my own. I had a TV prior to this one from Magnavox and it worked fine when connected to my PC via HDMI cabled. I have not tried restarting my PC, but the signal loss/gain happens immediately upon connecting the HDMI cable. I've tried 2 different HDMI cables, i have no available TV signal to connect it to, nor DVR.

Comment: Kind of sounds like you've narrowed it down to the TV.  If you just bought it, there may be a warranty solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an RCA android tablet on this model. This worked for me.

Go to menu/setup/hdmi control. Change CEC function to off. Change power off link to "NO". Then plug your device in ... go to input on remote ... choose your appropriate hdmi channel.